# How to change the FFT phase domain of each frame by 90 degrees

Tags: fft

I have read a signal in Matlab, resampled and implemented an FFT of each frame on it, now I want to rotate the domain of phase in each frame 90 degrees.

I have a vector of FFT and used the function named `rot90(matrix)`, that rotates a matrix 90 degrees, but I'm not sure it is what I wanted to work correctly on my function.

How can I do that in some other way?  Or does the `rot90` correctly work on changing the phase of domain in FFT which has been imported into a vector?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: implementing spectrogram function manually by math rules

Comment: I'm not really following. What does implementing a spectrogram function have to do with phase shifting the frequency vector?

Comment: well here are the steps of reaching a spectrogram : 1-we resample the input signal (inorder to have a clear spectrogram) 2- put each 10 sample(for example) into one window 3-make a fft of each window 4-rotate the phase domain of fft in each window  90 degree to draw the spectrogram of speech signal correctly

Comment: This doesn't sound right. Resampling is not needed. I'm not sure what you want with this, as oversampling will only add zeros at the frequencies above the original Nyquist frequency. Next, 10 samples in one frame is awkwardly little. You want a power of two (for good FFT performance) and something in the order of 256 to 2048. Finally, you don't do anything to the phases. You just take the magnitude of the result and show it. Where did you get your instructions from?

Comment: well im not sure about step 1 and your right... 10 sample was an example im sorry for that coz im a newbie in signal processing and speech recognition.Ive read it somewhere which explained about what is the spectrogram exactly doing on signals and what's its logic... You mean there is no need to rotate 90 degree?

Comment: You certainly don't have to rotate the *phase* for that. What you probably want is turning a row vector into a column vector to put it into the spectrogram matrix. That doesn't require anything special, other than possibly a transpose, which matlab does with the .' operator. So v.' is the transpose of v.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to plot the FFT such that the result is centered at 0, instead of at Fs. Matlab has a function for this [fftshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fftshift.html).

Here's a simple example when trying to plot either the onesided or twosided FFT.

```
f = 100; % Signal frequency (Hz)
fs = 1024; % Sampling frequency (Hz)
N = 1024; % Number of samples
Nfft = 1024; % FFT size

xf = 20*log10(abs(fft(x, Nfft))); % Compute the PSD

fw1 = fs * (0:Nfft/2)./Nfft; % Onesided domain
fw2 = fs * (-Nfft/2:Nfft/2-1)./Nfft; % Twosided domain

figure
subplot(211), plot(fw1, xf(1:Nfft/2+1)), title('Onesided')
subplot(212), plot(fw2, fftshift(xf)), title('Twosided')
```

Answer (score 0):

For a spectrogram you don't usually want to rotate the phase of each FFT result by 90 degrees (although one might do something similar for a Hilbert transformer).  Instead you want to rotate each FFT complex result so that it is strictly real, which is identical to calculating the FFT bin magnitudes, and mapping a row vector of magnitudes onto a column inside a 2D spectrogram matrix.